# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Значится, заделал я нейросеть, чтобы распознавать 4 символа:Греческие альфа и бета и плюс с минусом.
А она мне вот такую вот выдает ошибку.
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4800 but received input with shape [None, 4800, 4, 4]
Вот код https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QrVGPx1ZxmpBURUatlEiEAD88yfVhO2x?usp=sharing
Вот кусок

```
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, 4)
trainX = to_categorical(trainX, 4)
testY = to_categorical(testY, 4)
testX = to_categorical(testX, 4)
#input_shape=[1,0,0]
EPOCHS = 70
#checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/content/drive/MyDrive/handwritten_nums_train/point.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=32)
#model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=128, epochs=20, verbose=0, validation_data=(testX, testY), callbacks=[checkpointer])
print('Model trained')
```

Comment: я вам не советую добавлять код через различные ссылки. вы можете добавить код прямо в ваш вопрос скопировав его сюда и перед каждой строкой кода поставив четыре пробела. вы можете сказать что нормально, но не все такое расположение кода одобряют. поэтому не советую тестировать народный гнев

Comment: если у вас код очень длинный выберите тот кусочек где у вас происходит проблема и вставьте только его. а вообще почитайте тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, поможет

Comment: или вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask